# ressources file not taking in account

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm doing an ASP.NET web site. I want to localize it.
For the moment I've this :
- 2 ressources files (in localRessources folder)
- 2 linkbuttons in the master page (FR & EN) to change the langage manually

When I load the web site, I look for the user browser culture info and I set my current culture info to this and save this culture info id in the session state.
After, to fill my site, I get this id and ask the BD for the right content. This works fine.

The thing which doesn't work is the ressource files. It doesn't change between both when I click the button or when I change manually the culture of my browser.

After some test, I can say it comes from my code. Indeed, after I comment my code and change the culture of the browser, my content is setting fine...

So now my question is : how to change the culture of the client to use to correct culture when I ask my BD ? Which code ?

Please I need your help guys.
If it doesn't seem clear, ask for details ;-)

Skilpit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you set your current CultureInfo?

In MVC you should set it during Initialize (in the Controller class).

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) {
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
         System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
         new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

In ASP.NET WebForms you should set it at `InitializeCulture()`

Comment: I don't have both of those function...
I've a master page and a content page. I'm new in ASP.NET. I think I don't use a MVC ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys it's good now. I found this [tuto](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx). It's a very good one.
So Gidon. you're answer was also good. I tried to add Initialize in my master page. What is of course not possible ;-)

Comment: You could create a Base page , which derives from Page. In this base page you define the InitializeCulture() function. Each page you add will derive from BasePage. If I remember correct, the masterpage is called after your page.

Comment: yes indeed. It's what I did. Thanks for this additional explanations

Comment: I've just added a little more code in the InitializeCulture() to consider the culture of the client browser. The first time the client is connecting (or if the session is expired or aborded), is set the "preference" culture to the one of the browser.